# running transaction inside a loop doesn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I launch this code, only the first element creates a document in Firestore. Why is it stopping after one?

```
print("GMN:" + _newMemebrs.toString());


    FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction(
        (transaction) async {
           for (String elementnewMemebrs in _newMemebrs) {
            transaction.set(_groupMessageDoc, {
              'user': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
              'Read': [FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid],
            });
            }
          }
```

in the Debug console :

> flutter: GMN:[TJHS470POcTM8ree10SkhI7hQst1, WgZMKUy95lOSV9jnlQOE6hbCStS2,svTOwfmq93Q5VsreBgfG4bmgdqF3]

I can't share all the function but I print the list of string directly before running the transaction.

Comment: Can you please provide more context so we have a minimum, repeatable example? Specifically, where do the values _newMemebrs (is this a typo or the correct value?) and _groupMessageDoc come from?

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope, I hope what I added is enough